# jQuery AJAX call works on localhost not on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem which I can't solve at the moment. 
I have a WordPress AJAX login on my website from this example:
http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way

On my localhost everything is working fine and can login. On the live server I can't login and the response is always 0

In my login.php I have this code:

```
function cted_ajax_login_init() {

wp_register_script( 'ajax-login-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-login.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login-js' );

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-js', 'ajax_login_object', array(
    'ajaxurl'           => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl'       => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'loadingmessage'    => __('Gegevens verifiëren, een ogenblik ...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'cted_ajax_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxlogin', 'cted_ajax_login' );
}

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
add_action( 'init', 'cted_ajax_login_init' );
}
```

The ajax function:

```
function cted_ajax_login(){

// First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

// Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$info['remember'] = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_signon ) ) {
    $response = ( array(
        'loggedin'  => false,
        'message'   => __(),
        'error'    => $user_signon->get_error_message(),
    ) );
} else {
    $response = ( array(
        'loggedin'  => true,
        'message'   => __(),
    ) );
}

wp_send_json( $response );

}
```

And the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Perform AJAX login on form submit
$('form#login').on('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'ajaxlogin',
            username: $('form#login #username').val(),
            password: $('form#login #password').val(),
            security: $('form#login #security').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
            if(data.loggedin == true ) {
                 $('#loginmsg').addClass('bs-callout bs-callout-success');
                document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
            }
            else {
                $('#loginmsg').addClass('bs-callout bs-callout-danger');
            }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });

});

});
```

Comment: Check that you have uploaded all files to the server.

Comment: It seems that when a login with incorrect username/password is executed and with correct username/password returns 0

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes they all are

Comment: do you have your sql database set up on the live server? Do you have permissions to these files? Once I uploaded files using cyber duck and it changed the permissions of the files by accident and I could not use them.

Comment: Files are uploaded through the WordPress file uploader, so permissions are ok.